# Surjectivity of $\lceil x/2\rceil$ over the integers

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is the following function surjective from the set of integers to the set of integers?
$$\lceil x/2\rceil$$
My initial intuition says that it is, but I don't know if once the element $x$ from the domain starts getting higher in value (when $x$ approaches infinity), it would eventually miss an integer.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: What happens if $x=2n,$ $n$ an integer?

Comment: @ChrisLeary you get the double value of n.

Comment: I believe you should get $n.$ Check Parclay's answer below.

Comment: @ChrisLeary yes, I understand now. If 2*n = x in the original equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any integer $y$ pick $x=2y$, which is an integer. Then $x/2$ is an integer, and since the ceiling of an integer is itself, $\lceil x/2\rceil=y$. Therefore the function has a preimage for every element in its codomain and is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\lceil (2n)/2\rceil = n$.